# How to add layerSwitcher to a specific div

Tags: openlayers, geoportal

I'm trying to add a control in a specific panel (`<div>`) which will groups others controls. I tried many things but nothing with succes.
It seems I didn't catch the option [target](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.control.Control.html).

Maybe somebody could help me with this ?

Comment: what is your openlayers version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I resolved it, it was a question of order, my div was not created yet when I tried to add the control. By the way my openlayers version is 4.6.4